# Angular and node api in iisnode directory structure in iisnode not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, iis, iisnode

[Ref to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46958685/how-to-setup-iisnode-with-express)
I am running node api and angular component through IISnode. In ref to above question. I have deployed to IIS, I have Angular and node api in different folders, so when I browse the application from IIS server, it shows in different directories as shown in pic below[image: How] and I have shown virtual directory structure of iisnode below.

[image: iisnode directory structure]

When I click on the client I see angular and node api working as expected, but I want this to happen without clicking on client as shown below.

**Please note: I have app.js and web.config as shown in the question above**

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to point any request in web.config to app.js,and app.js had the logic to divert to where it is needed.

```
 <rule name="api">
    <match url="api/*" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="app.js" />
  </rule>
```